# ValueError: A BigQuery table or a query must be specified

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My cloud function is to form a dynamic query based on certain rules and store it in file into cloud stoarage and further it will call my dataflow template.I am passing inputfile as ValueProvider to my dataflow template which is holding a query, Further I am trying to use that query in my pipeline with beam.io.BigQuerySource. But it is giving me an error : ValueError: A BigQuery table or a query must be specified

Some Cloud Function code:

```
query_job = client.query(
        query,
        job_config=job_config)
    query_job.result()
    print('Query results loaded to table {}'.format(table_ref.path))
    file_name = '{}_RM_{}.csv'.format(unit, datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')[:-3])
    destination_uri = "gs://test-bucket/{}".format(file_name)
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=PROJECT)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri)
    extract_job.result() #Extracts results to the GCS
    client.delete_table(table_ref) #Deletes table in BQ


    BODY = {
        "jobName": "{jobname}".format(jobname=JOBNAME),
        "parameters": {
            "inputFile": destination_uri
        },
        "environment": {
            "tempLocation": "gs://{bucket}/temp".format(bucket=BUCKET),
            "zone": "europe-west1-b"
        }
    }

    request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=PROJECT, gcsPath=GCSPATH, body=BODY)
    response = request.execute()
```

Dataflow code:

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--inputFile', default='query.txt')


class Query:
    def query_final(self, inputFile):
        from google.cloud import storage
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.get_bucket('ingka-retention-test-bucket')
        blob = bucket.get_blob(str(inputFile))
        return blob
def dataflow():
    options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary(pipeline_options)
    user_options = options.view_as(UserOptions)

    inputFile = user_options.inputFile
    new_query = Query()
    final_query = new_query.query_final(inputFile)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        rows = p | 'Read Orders from BigQuery ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=final_query, use_standard_sql=True))
```

What will be the cause or any other best approach to achieve this task?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with BigQuery source as the statement is required at graph compile time. The source and the settings are locked at compile time.

Solution: You could use the BQ API inline within in ParDo and parameterize the code similar to what you have done above. That is interpreted at runtime. To kick off your ParDo you'd construct a PCollection of some number of items that correspond to the N times you'd want to make the call. Keep in mind you will have to deal with any  idempotency  issues if there was a failure in your overall ParDo scope.

[[How to run dynamic second query in google cloud dataflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713939/how-to-run-dynamic-second-query-in-google-cloud-dataflow][1])